# Getting a threadlocal error while deploying to tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, memory, memory-leaks

I have problem in deploying a grails project to the tomcat webapp directory.

Looking into the `catalina.out` log file I can see the following error:

```
SEVERE: The web application [/test-0.1] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Dec 24, 2012 10:41:52 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/test-0.1] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory$2] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory$2@57390ad3]) and a value of type [java.lang.Boolean] (value [false]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

I'm very new to Tomcat and not sure what these errors mean. Kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide the version of tomcat and grails  :)

Comment: grails 1.3.7 and tomcat 6

Answer (score 2):

Copy the JDBC driver jar file to tomcat/lib directory would solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did the JDBC Driver exist on your classpath ?

To fix that, create a folder lib on your jquery plugin

e.g  `~/.grails/2.1.0/projects/YourProject/plugins/jquery-1.x.x/lib`

and copy the JDBC Driver jar on this folder.

Hope this help.

Comment: for my jquery plugin??? Can you be more elaborate on why should I put jar on jquery plugin?

Comment: i know, it's not good, but it's an easy way to fix the trouble with the jdbc driver, it will automaticly loaded in your classpath.